# launch testem chrome browser with specific extension(s)

Tags: google-chrome, ember.js, google-chrome-extension, testem

I am trying to have `Testem` launching my tests into Chrome browser with specific extension(s) loaded, but by default it's a blank Chrome profile which is started, and which doesn't persist extensions from one run to another.

My goal is for example having `Testem` to launch the Chrome browser pre-loaded with the `Ember  Inspector` so that I can debug tests using that tool.

I wanted to know if that is possible, and if so, how.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/testem/testem/issues/808

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a built-in way that I can find.

If you want a quick and dirty solution, I recommend the following:

The available browsers in `testem` are defined in `testem/lib/browser_launcher.js` If you want to modify the file that `ember-cli` uses, this will be the full path:

```
<your-app-dir>/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/testem/lib/browser_launcher.js
```

This file has a function called `browsersForPlatform()`. Find your platform and the entry for Chrome. For Darwin the relevant entry is as follows:

```
      {
        name: "Chrome", 
        exe: "/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome", 
        args: ["--user-data-dir=" + tempDir + "/testem.chrome", "--no-default-browser-check", "--no-first-run", "--ignore-certificate-errors"],
        setup: function(config, done){
          rimraf(tempDir + '/testem.chrome', done)
        },
        supported: browserExeExists
      },
```

You'll want to change the `args` so it gets called as you like. My guess is the problem is that `--user-data-dir` points to a tmp directory. Perhaps simply removing this will solve the problem.

Ideally, testem would offer a way in the testem.json file to override browser options. This would probably be a reasonably straightforward contribution to the testem project if you're interested and there is interest among the maintainers.

If you go the route of changing `browser_launcher.js` just remember that it will get clobbered every time the node package gets updated. I assume there is a way you can install a forked version and then keep your copy up to date as you see fit.

Comment: You can use npm-shrinkwrap.json to force ember-cli to use a forked version of testem. Chrome arguments are now in [lib/utils/known-browsers.js](https://github.com/testem/testem/blob/v1.9.1/lib/utils/known-browsers.js#L22-L33)